# How to increase number of sockets on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm trying to run the same batch process(Linux) on Equinix VM and and EC2 instance. The configuration of the machines are same, yet the EC2 process is running 10x slower than the equinix one. 
Found the difference in sockets. 8 sockets in Equinix, while only 1 in EC2 (from lscpu)

Note: the batch process utilizes WebURL to fetch features.

I figured out maybe increasing the sockets while launching the instance and then trying to run, shall match up the pace of equinix VM.

Any leads on how to go about doing it? Or any other hints to improve the performance of the EC2 instance?

Comment: What other loads is on these two instances, and are you certain that it is the same in both cases?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen No other load on these instances. I used exact same parameters to run the job.

Comment: Moreover, the EC2 instance has the latest kernel version, while Equinix instance has an outdated one.Yet the performance is much better in Equinix instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration of the machines are same"? What Amazon EC2 instance type are you using? Smaller instances have limited network bandwidth, which might be impacting your task. Basically, the only thing you can change is the Instance Type, which will give you a certain amount of hardware allocation.

Comment: Sockets shouldn't matter. Try comparing how many CPU cores both machines have.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm using M5.2x large. any suggestions for better network then?

Comment: @SergeyKovalev  Both have 8 CPU cores

Comment: The m5.2xlarge is good from a networking perspective. Next thing is to figure out what is the constrained resource -- it would be one of CPU, RAM or Networking. You can monitor processes (eg `top`) to see how much CPU and memory they are using. However, if our application is single-threaded, it might only use one CPU regardless of how many CPUs are provided. Can/does your app use multi-threading?

Comment: @John Rotenstein yes, my application uses multi-threading. Will take your suggestion to check how much memory it's utilizing. Nonetheless, in this case sockets have no role to affect the performance of the application?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein ,
I finally found the core issue was with EBS volume type for my EC2 instances. I changed it to Provisioned IOPS and it worked. The performance is better than the Equinix VMs.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I guess I have to add "Disk Speed" to the standard checklist of CPU, Memory and Network.